# Docker swarm with a custom network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm trying to work out how to properly use swarm mode in Docker. First I tried running containers on my 2 workers and manager machine without specifying a custom network (so I'm using the default ingress overlay network). However, If I use the ingress network, for some reason I cannot resolve `tasks.myservice`.

So I tried configuring a custom network like this:

```
docker network create -d overlay elasticnet
```

So now, when I `bash` into one of the containers, I can successfully resolve `tasks.myservice` but I can no longer access the port I've defined in my service creation under `--publish` externally (which I could when I used the ingress network).

Is there any way of either:

1. Use the ingress network and be able to resolve `tasks.myservice` or any other DNS record that will direct to all of my service containers?
2. Or, use a custom network, but `--publish` ports correctly so I could access them externally?

**EDIT**

This is how I create my service,

Without a custom network:

```
docker service create --replicas 3 --label elasticsearch --endpoint-mode vip --name elastic -e ES_HOSTS="tasks.elastic" --publish 9200:9200 --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/es,destination=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config  --update-delay 10s   es:latest
```

With a custom network:

```
docker service create --replicas 3 --network elasticnet --label elasticsearch --endpoint-mode vip --name elastic -e ES_HOSTS="tasks.elastic" --publish 9200:9200 --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/es,destination=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config  --update-delay 10s   es:latest
```

Comment: Can you post a list of all the commands you're running please? And the user-defined overlay network is the way to go.

Comment: @johnharris85 Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example below:

1.Create user defined overlay network:

```
sudo docker network create overlay1 --driver overlay
9g4ipjn513iy        overlay1            overlay             swarm
```

2.Run a service with exposed ports and 3 replicas:

```
sudo docker service create --name nginx --replicas 3 --publish 80:80 --network overlay1 nginx
```

You dont have to specify `endpoint-mode` if you gonna use `VIP`, its the default.

```
sudo docker service  ps nginx
ID                         NAME     IMAGE  NODE  DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR
dbz8b4jjfp6xg3vqunt1x8shx  nginx.1  nginx  dg1   Running        Running 13 minutes ago  
9d8zr6zka0sp99vadr8eqq2t2  nginx.2  nginx  dg3   Running        Running 13 minutes ago  
cwbcegunuxz5ye9a8ghdrc4fg  nginx.3  nginx  dg3   Running        Running 12 minutes ago
```

3.Verification:
Testing Exposed port from one of the nodes:

```
administrator@dg1:~$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Testing exposed port from external host:

```
user@externalhost /home/balrog% telnet dg1 80
Trying 172.30.135.101...
Connected to 172.30.135.101.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Testing DNS lookup from inside of containers:

```
sudo docker exec -it 05d05f934c68 /bin/bash
root@05d05f934c68:/# ping nginx                                                                                                                                         
PING nginx (10.0.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms

root@05d05f934c68:/# ping tasks.nginx 
PING tasks.nginx (10.0.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
```

**ElasticSearch Specific Suggestion**:

Elasticseach has its own clustering that provides `Failover` and `Loadbalancing` features.

You can use `shards` and `replicas` per `index` in elasticsearch hosts that are part of elasticsearch cluster.

This being said, I suggest you create 3 `Services` with 1 `replica` each, then join then in an elasticsearch cluster, then create `indexes` with 3 `shards` and 3 `replicas`. You will have `loadbalancing` and `failover` within elasticsearch cluster.

To read more about `shards`, [Use this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html).

Answer (score 0):

What we're missing here is your service definition, or are you using just good old fashion docker run when defining your containers.

If you've used the docker service functionality (available in docker 1.12), you could still expose your ports by service

```
docker create --name nodejs1 --network anti-spam -p 1230:123 --replicas 1 image:version
```

Your service would get created on the anti-spam network and if you created another service nodejs2, they would be able to reach each other using the service name like a hostname.

Publishing would still work on the swarm, but each host would listen for port 1230 and then mesh route it to one of the containers.

Comment: Please see my edit. The thing is, when I use `-p 1230:123` for example, doesn't that mean that port 1230 should be available externally? If yes, I can't get that part to work with a custom network.