# How to connect to Postgresql service inside Docker Swarm?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jdbc, docker-swarm-mode

I have a Docker Swarm cluster setup with 3 servers(1 manager and 2 workers).

I started a Postgresql service using the command below:

```
docker service create --name postgresql \
  --mount src=pg_data,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
  -p 6542:5432 \
  -e POSTGRES_USER="user" \
  -e POSTGRES_DB="db" \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="pass" \
  -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
  --constraint 'node.role == manager' \
  postgres
```

I also created the data volume previously:

```
docker volume create pg_data
```

Now, I have another service that I want to start, which is basically a Java application that I bundled into a Docker image and I want to connect it to the postgresql service. I tried the following combinations for the url:

> jdbc:postgresql://172.18.0.1:5432/db (docker_gwbridge)
>
> jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.1:5432/db (docker0)
>
> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
>
> jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/db

Any idea what could work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shall use a swarm [`overlay network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/) to connect to your database inside swarm mode.

First create the overlay network:

```
docker network create -d overlay mynet
```

Then make your `postgresql` service use this network:

```
docker service create --name postgresql \
  --mount ... \
  --network mynet \
  postgres
```

Then, don't forget to use the same network for your Java application container:

```
docker service create --name myjavaapp \
  --network mynet \
  myjavaapp
```

Then you can connect to your `postgresql` through DNS name like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/db
```

All service's containers in the `mynet` network (you can call it as you want, it's just a name reference), have DNS entries corresponding to service name. This is easier than having to retrieve container's IP through `docker inspect` before launching your java application.

You can even avoid the `publish` port `-p 6542:5432` in your postgresql docker service as your probably don't want to expose this to others.

You can have a look at the [official doc to better understand networks in swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/).

This [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911124/docker-swarm-with-a-custom-network) also talks about overlay network.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` try target `target=/var/lib/postgresql/data`